# Detect change in realm database and update remote database android

Tags: android, database, mobile, realm

Is there a way to detect if a realm database is changed?

I am logging the user activity on the android app. I want to update the backend with the updated values in local realm database whenever there is a change in local. So that my backend is always in sync with the local database.

Comment: I have updated my answer. check and respond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [Realm Documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/)

-Add change listener.

-Add data

-The change is instantly reflected in onChangeListener.

```
private RealmResults<Dog> puppies;

// ...

puppies = realm.where(Dog.class).lessThan("age", 2).findAll();
puppies.size(); // => 0

realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    void public execute(Realm realm) {
        Dog dog = realm.createObject(Dog.class);
        dog.setName("Fido");
        dog.setAge(1);
    }
});

puppies.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(RealmResults<Dog> results) {
      // results and puppies point are both up to date
      results.size(); // => 1
      puppies.size(); // => 1
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
 localRealm.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<Realm>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(Realm realm) {
            //do stuff
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think the change listener you added *after* the transaction would only be called on Realm 0.89.0 to 2.x.x, and it is no longer the case since Realm 3.x. I think.

Comment: I'm using 4.2.0 version and implementing `RealmChangeListener<Realm>` interface, and i am getting callback in `onChange`. But it was mentioned on doc, you are right, one have to register listener before.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce what do you think about having realm change listener in andriod Application class ? Can it be problemetic ?

Comment: @humble_wolf nobody stops you, but make sure you keep a reference to the RealmResults as a field variable